# Count distinct users over n-days

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, window-functions

My table consists of two fields, `CalDay` a timestamp field with time set on 00:00:00 and `UserID`.
Together they form a compound key but it is important to have in mind that we have many rows for each given calendar day and there is no fixed number of rows for a given day.

Based on this dataset I would need to calculate how many distinct users there are over a set window of time, say 30d.

Using postgres 9.3 I cannot use `COUNT(Distinct UserID) OVER ...` nor I can work around the issue using `DENSE_RANK() OVER (... RANGE BETWEEN)` because `RANGE` only accepts `UNBOUNDED`.

So I went the old fashioned way and tried with a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT
  xx.*
 ,(
       SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID) 
       FROM data_table AS yy
       WHERE yy.CalDay BETWEEN xx.CalDay - interval '30 days' AND xx.u_ts
  ) as rolling_count
FROM data_table AS xx
ORDER BY yy.CalDay
```

In theory, this should work, right? I am not sure yet because I started the query about 20 mins ago and it is still running. Here lies the problem, the dataset is still relatively small (25000 rows) but will grow over time. I would need something that scales and performs better.

I was thinking that maybe - just maybe - using the unix epoch instead of the timestamp could help but it is only a wild guess. Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: In theory it will work, yes. However as you've seen it's very inefficient. Can you give an example of the actual results you want, as you said you can have many rows in a given day, and your query will calculate/return the count for every one of those rows, not one result per day. So I'm not sure what you expect the actual output to look like.

Comment: In terms of **final** result I will need one row per date with the count of distinct users on that given date and the count of distinct users in the last 30 days window.

As an intermediate goal I am fine with keeping many rows per day, as then I can just use MAX()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* work. Can't comment on speed, but should be a lot less than your current one. Hopefully you have indexes on both these fields.

```
SELECT t1.calday, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.userid) AS daily, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.userid) AS last_30_days
FROM data_table t1
JOIN data_table t2
    ON t2.calday BETWEEN t1.calday - '30 days'::INTERVAL AND t1.calday
GROUP BY t1.calday
```

**UPDATE**

Tested it with a lot of data. The above works but is slow. Much faster to do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.userid) AS last_30_days
FROM (
    SELECT calday, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS daily
    FROM data_table
    GROUP BY calday
) t1
JOIN data_table t2
    ON t2.calday BETWEEN t1.calday - '30 days'::INTERVAL AND t1.calday
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

So instead of building up a massive table for all the JOIN combinations and then grouping/aggregating, it first gets the "daily" data, then joins the 30 day on that. Keeps the join much smaller and returns quickly (just under 1 second for 45000 rows in the source table on my system).

Comment: I often forget that we have non-equi joins. It works like a charm, it is scalable (one thing I haven't mentioned here is that I will need also another field with a 7 day window). By wrapping your query within another `SELECT` this worked amazingly fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small postgres example.  It brings along the dummy counting variable but you can shed that later.  Not an expert on performance but I think it will work OK.  LMK if you have a better idea.

```
drop table if exists userdays;

create table userdays
(
    activedate date,
    uid int
)
;

insert into userdays
values
('9-23-2023',1),
('9-23-2023',3),
('9-24-2023',1),
('9-24-2023',2),
('9-24-2023',3),
('9-25-2023',1),
('9-25-2023',2),
('9-25-2023',3),
('9-25-2023',4),
('9-26-2023',1),
('9-26-2023',2),
('9-26-2023',3),
('9-26-2023',4),
('9-27-2023',1),
('9-27-2023',2),
('9-27-2023',3),
('9-27-2023',4)
;


select
activity_date
,ucount
,sum(ucount) uad
,sum(ucount) over (order by t1.activity_date rows between 3 preceding and current row) au3d
from
(
    select
    to_date(t1.activedate::text,'YYYY-MM-DD') activity_date
    ,t1.uid
    ,1 ucount
    ,count(*)
    from userdays t1
    group by 1,2,3
) t1
group by 1,ucount
order by 1 desc,ucount
;
```